# adb cannot bind 'tcp:5037'

Tags: android, adb

It used to work fine, but today after I connected my Android phone to my machine, and run `adb devices`, I got the following error:

```
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
cannot bind 'tcp:5037': Address already in use
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error: cannot connect to daemon: Operation timed out
```

How to solve this problem? (I am using a MacBook)

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/814386/adb-fails-with-cannot-bind-local5037

Comment: @TimCastelijns, my problem is different than the linked one you provided. Read carefully. The linked problem has error `cannot bind 'local:5037'` but my problem has error `cannot bind 'TCP:5037'`

Comment: I don't claim it's a dupe. Just providing some information in case it may be useful

Answer (score 19):

**Try with following commands**

Find port details by `List Open Files` **lsof**  command.

`sudo lsof -i :5037` and find **PID** and kill it.

`kill -9 <pid here>`

Example: `kill -9 4363`

Then start adb server. `adb devices` command.

Answer (score 8):

Kill the Adb server and restart.

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

[image]

Comment: didn't help me. start server still throws error `cannot bind 'tcp:5038'`

Answer (score 5):

I managed to solve this problem on `MacBook` by first running the following command to list the process which is using port `5037`

```
lsof -n -i4TCP:5037 | grep LISTEN
```

Then, I kill it:

```
kill -9 <PID>
```

Then, `adb devices` works!

Answer (score 3):

1. Android Studio Terminal

`$ adb devices`

```
List of devices attached
adb server is out of date.  killing...
cannot bind 'tcp:5037': Address already in use
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error: 
error:
```

2. OS Terminal

`$ adb devices`

```
List of devices attached
adb server is out of date.  killing...
* daemon started successfully *
```

3. Finally test again at the IDE terminal

`$ adb devices`

```
List of devices attached
```

GL

Answer (score 1):

it is clear that `Address already in use`. `busybox netstat -antp` to check who is using the port.

Comment: Yes , error message is clear that `address is in use`, but I am not sure how to list all the processes using that port & kill them

Comment: and what is `busybox`? I don't want to install extra tool to solve this problem.

Comment: Check this answer which helped me. The issue might be with the latest unstable version of platform-tools.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43131020/adb-cannot-connect-to-daemon-at-tcp5037

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed the problem by updating the Android SDK.

```
android update sdk --no-ui
```

Additionally, I've updated the Platform Tools to the newest version.

---

**If this doesn't work**, redownload android sdk.

- `wget http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.2-linux.tgz`
- `tar -xvf android-sdk_r24.2-linux.tgz cd android-sdk-linux/tools`
- install all sdk packages
- `./android update sdk --no-ui`

Answer (score 0):

I tried it at the OS Terminal, worked.

Try on the OS terminal first

Answer (score 0):

Running the following command at the OS bash helped solve the issue:

```
sudo adb start-server
```

Answer (score -1):

I ran adb kill command and then it started working fine

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```