# Downgrade adb from 1.0.39 to 1.0.36

Tags: adb

I can't comment this topic because I don't have enough reputation :
[adb cannot connect to daemon at tcp:5037](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43131020/adb-cannot-connect-to-daemon-at-tcp5037/43239887#43239887)

I have exactely the same problem. I hope my question will not be deleted because it's the same topic...

Teacher-too said :

> Thank you for your answer。My system is MAC OS。The problem solved。 Reason is the latest system and adb 1.0.39 incompatible。 I use the adb 1.0.36 was no problem。 – teacher-too Apr 6 at 1:43

I would like to do this but I didn't find how to downgrade adb. I found this : https://github.com/simmac/minimal_adb_fastboot but it doesn't work. The `uninstall-old` argument said "`Uninstall successful!`" but `adb version` still returns

`Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39
Revision 5943271ace17-android`

I tried several times but it seems like everything is always good using this package.

Can you explain how did you downgrade adb please ?