# adb devices is not listing the devices

Tags: android, adb

`adb devices` is not listing the attached device instead the command hangs for ever. As per the suggestion given here in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43466238/6680585) killed the process which is running on port 5037 but after killing once it's listing the devices for me.

The next time when i enter `adb devices` the command hangs for ever. Any help in this regard would be much appreciated.

**Additional information:**

- Running this command on MacOS Mojave 10.14.6

Comment: You should probably include some environment information, like version numbers, OS...etc.

Comment: Sure @RyanMentley. Edited the question with the environment information

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is some issue with the platform-tools which is installed in my machine. Downloaded the platform-tools given from this link

https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/

And replaced ~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools with the downloaded one. It worked.