# Visual Studio 2022 Android Debugging Works on One and Not Another Phone

Tags: android, debugging, xamarin, connection-refused

I have a Mac and am running Visual Studio 2022 for Mac Arm.

I cannot debug on my Android 12 Samsung A135U. I can debug on my Pixel 3 with Android 11. I also have another Android 12 Samsung A535G and it works fine, so it seems to be this one phone.

```
Forwarding debugger port 8814
Detecting existing process
> am start -a "android.intent.action.MAIN" -n 
"com.holley.msd.msd6al/crc6440ee73e2d8c95812.SplashActivity"
> Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN 
cmp=com.holley.msd.msd6al/crc6440ee73e2d8c95812.SplashActivity }
```

On the phone I am seeing this message:

```
E/adbd: failed to connect to socket 'tcp:8814': Connection refused
```

I found this post which looked really similar.

[When debugging with an Android device I get a 'Failed to connect to socket' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71003685/when-debugging-with-an-android-device-i-get-a-failed-to-connect-to-socket-erro)

The MS person who replied suggested this other post:

[adb cannot connect to daemon at tcp:5037](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43131020/adb-cannot-connect-to-daemon-at-tcp5037)

I tried all of those things and none of them worked for me.

The thing that I think may help you figure this out in my case is that my other 2 phones works fine.

I can debug and step through code and hit breakpoints all just fine.

It is just the Android 12 Samsung A135U that doesn't work.

I set it up the same with all the same settings.

I tried using Wireless debugging just to see if that would make a difference, but get the same results.

I have followed all steps I can find to enable debugging and did it exactly the same on the phone that works and the one that doesn't.

Please advise....

Comment: *"tried many things, but nothing works"*: What have you tried, that did not work? (If you don't list those, then you are likely to get suggestions that you have already tried.)

Comment: "I am seeing that message a lot of people see" - please post the exact error, not a vague description.  And have you verified that you can connect to the device with adb?  Have you followed all the steps to enable debugging?  Have you checked if any special drivers are required?  Have you tried USB instead of wireless?

Comment: Thank you both for your comments to help me improve my query. for those who won't see the edit comments I made changed to the original post in response to the above comments.

Comment: I didn't have device Android 12 Samsung A135U. Have you tested on android emulators?

Comment: It works fine on the emulators and on 2 other phones. One with Android 11 and one with Android 12. I need help figuring out how to get it to work on this one phone.