# error: cannot connect to daemon at tcp:5037

Tags: java, firebase, flutter, dart, java-11

i want to uninstall the app from the device flutter and i use this command:

```
adb uninstall com.example.application
```

but this give me error

```
Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (10048)
```

Please can someone help me

I've tried many of the suggestions and none have worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried killing or stopping  the process that is currently running on that port ?

ps aux | grep 5037

kill -9 'running process id'

for instance :

ps aux | grep 5037

12814   0.0  0.0 34140220    872 s000  S+    4:06PM   0:00.00 grep 5037

then:
kill -9 12814

Could you also see the solution here [adb cannot connect to daemon at tcp:5037](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43131020/adb-cannot-connect-to-daemon-at-tcp5037)